# how to display woocommerce cart count and update this when user click on the add to cart ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to show the user how many products he has in his shopping cart in the header of my WooCommerce site. So far, everything was great with this: `<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?>`, but when the user clicked on the add to cart button, this number was not updated and the information The error was displayed to the user
My html code is like this:

```
<div id="HeaderLeft">
                <ul>
                    <li id="CartBox"><a href="/cart/"><iconify-icon icon="fluent:cart-24-regular"></iconify-icon></a><span><?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(); ?></span></li>
                    <li><a href="/my-account/"><iconify-icon icon="fluent:person-48-regular"></iconify-icon></a></li>
                    <li><a href="tel:<?php the_field('Telephone', 'option'); ?>"><?php the_field('Telephone', 'option'); ?><iconify-icon icon="fluent:call-48-regular"></iconify-icon></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using a piece of JavaScript code in which I also used jQuery.

```
$(document.body).on('added_to_cart', function (event, fragments, cart_hash, button) {
        // Get the cart count and update it
        var cartCount = fragments['div.widget_shopping_cart_content'].split('<span class=\"quantity\">');
        var TotalCount = 0;
        for (let index = 1; index < cartCount.length; index++) {
            var item = cartCount[index];
            var ItemCount = item.split(' &times;')[0];
            TotalCount += parseInt(ItemCount);
        }
        $('#CartBox span').text(TotalCount);
    });
```

This code receives the information of the shopping cart, and then by separating the information into minus and minus and adding the numbers, it displays the total number next to the icon of your shopping cart.